# swift 3.0 UISlider left thumbs

Tags: swift, uislider

This's code,

```
slider = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 80,y: 9.5,width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 160,height: 15))
slider.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.orange
slider.isContinuous = false
slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pageChange), for: .valueChanged)
slider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named:"RM_3"), for: .normal)
bottomBar?.addSubview(slider)
```

How to clean up the left thumbs???

[image: slider]

Comment: What is bottom bar ? And Please show RM_3 Image that you have used for slider's Thumb Image.

Comment: You need to check your Bottom Bar as Code for Slider is Okay and its Working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IN Swift 3.0**

```
import UIKit


class DBSlider: UISlider {

    @IBInspectable var thumbImage: UIImage?
    @IBInspectable var minTrackColor:UIColor?
    @IBInspectable var maxTrackColor:UIColor?


    // MARK: Lifecycle

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        if let thumbImage = thumbImage
        {0
            self.setThumbImage(thumbImage, for: .normal)
        }
        if let minTrackColor = minTrackColor
        {
            self.minimumTrackTintColor = minTrackColor
        }
        if let maxTrackColor = maxTrackColor
        {
            self.maximumTrackTintColor = maxTrackColor
        }

    }
}
```

[image][image]
[image]